# Django (CBV) how to display form for comments beneath the post?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, django-2.1

I have button 'add comment' beneath the post, that redirects to URL with form for comment and it works fine but...
I would like to have this form displayed beneath the post.

I tried including URL with comment form in `post_detail.html` template but got errors about form not being valid. When I passed form to `PostDetail()` context it was displayed but now working.

**How do I combine `PostDetail()` with my `CommentForm()` to be displayed at the same URL?**

Here are parts of my code :

models.py

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    text_html = models.TextField(editable=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.text_html = misaka.html(self.text)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Comment
        fields = ('text',)
```

views.py

```py
class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))

...

@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk, **kwargs):
    post = get_object_or_404(models.Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('posts:single', username=post.user, pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = forms.CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'posts/comment_form.html',{'form': form})
```

post_detail.html

```html
{% extends "posts/post_base.html" %}

{% block post_content %}
  <div class="col-md">
    {% include "posts/_post.html" %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block post_post %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div class="container comments">

    <!-- COMMENTS FORM IN HERE -->

    <a class="btn btn-primary add-comment" id="add-comment" href="{% url 'posts:add_comment' username=post.user.username pk=post.pk %}">Add Comment</a>
    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <div class="jumbotron comment">
        <p>{{ comment.author }} <span>{{ comment.created_at }}</span></p>
      <p>{{ comment.text_html|safe }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I will be very thankful for at least explaining what steps do I need to take to reach described outcome.

Comment: Can you show us the version where you are including the form and the specific error(s) you are getting?

Comment: when I do ```{% include "posts/comment_form.html" %}``` i get ```Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form```. I know its is realted with form not being passed to template, but I dont know how to solve it without hard coding ```add_comment_to_post()``` to ```PostDetail()```

Comment: When you include the `posts/comment_form.html` you'd need to add a new `forms.CommentForm()` to the context data. Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried. I had form displayed but it was not working (with redirecting to other URL it works fine).